# webpack plugins generate and inject script files at the end of the body element

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I have just completed a class that shows how to use webpack with plugins to auto generate script tags that chunk vendor files.  I am using webpack 1.14.0, the plugins in question are HtmlWebpackPlugin and CommonsChunkPlugin.  Everything is working but I wanted to extend this to my angular work.  So the vendor bundle contains angular library -- but the problem is that the script references generated get inserted at the end of the  element whereas my angular code is higher up -- thus causing "angular is not defined" error at runtime.  If I was to manually move the script references higher up, everything works.   So my question is: how do I control the placement of the script files injected by webpack in my html file?  thank you

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myStudyApp">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('myStudyApp', []);

        app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        }]);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        Simple Angular Hello World with the first controller
        <input ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter your name here">
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- I need this higher up!  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.540c10d13f2e24eb3d7c.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.52c954c6bebf14f9d52d.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: so did a lot of digging -- got to the point where my injected scripts are now part of the head element, but still at the bottom. I dont understand why isnt everyone else who uses angular and bundles their projects using webpack does not have the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Generally your JS code would be in a separate file, but we can work with it in your HTML. Now that you've gotten your vendor & main up into `<head>` the simplest thing to do would be to move your code down, just above `</body>` like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myStudyApp', []);

    app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    }]);
  </script>
</body>
```

I've never had this problem because I don't use the hash option for the output file names. My files are named `vendor.min.js` and `app.min.js`.

Hope this helps!